# python - how to get shc.linkage ordered leaves?

Tags: scipy, correlation, hierarchical-clustering, linkage, dendrogram

I'm making a dendrogram and after a correlogram, and I want them to have the same order of labels. In order to do that, I'd like to save in a variable the labels of the dendrogram in the order they appear.

So if, this code:

```
clusters = shc.linkage(df.dropna().T, 'single', 'correlation', optimal_ordering=True)
dend = shc.dendrogram(clusters, orientation='left', labels=df.columns)
```

plots top-bottom (D,B,A,C,E...G) leaves, I'd like to save in a variable this ordered list of leaves ordering=(D,B,A,C,E...G).

Thank you in advance.